# I am looking for some suggestions/tricks/help solving this PHP exercise

Tags: php

I am trying to get a list of string,ints from an input form with numOfString to generate, minStringLength(1) and maxStringLength(100). Just starting off with PHP and I cannot get it to work. Any help or suggestions? I have tried several ways and following is one of them.

```
<?php
    //variables
    $reqString = $_POST['reqString'];
    $minString = $_POST['minString'];
    $maxString = $_POST['maxString'];
    function generateRandomString($minString, $maxString) {
        $strings = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        // $stringRequested = reqString;
        // $stringMinLength = minString;
        // $stringMaxLength = maxString;
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['reqString']; $i++) {
            $randomString = $strings[rand($minString, $maxString)];
        }
        return $randomString; 
        array($randomString);
    }
    echo generateRandomString($minString, $maxString);
    //printf($randomString);

    //something I found online
    // $n=range(11,20);
    // shuffle($n);
    // for ($x=0; $x< 10; $x++)
    // {
    // echo $n[$x].' ';
    // }
    // echo "\n"



        //variables
    //$reqInteger = $_POST['reqInteger'];
    //$minInteger = $_POST['minInteger'];
    //$maxInteger = $_POST['maxInteger'];
    // function generateRandomInteger($reqInteger, $minInteger, $maxInteger) {
    // $integers = '0123456789';
    // $integerRequested = reqInteger;
    // $integerMinLength = minInteger;
    // $integerMaxLength = maxInteger;
    // $randomInteger = '';
    //   for ($i = 0; $i < $integerRequested; $i++) {
    //     $randomInteger .= $integers[mt_rand($integerMinLength, $integerMaxLength)];
    //   }
    // return $randomInteger;
    // }
    // echo generateRandomInteger($reqInteger, $minInteger, $maxInteger);
    // echo $randomInteger;
```

Comment: If you want to append to a string, it should be `$randomString .= thingToAppend;`. You're just replacing the string each time through the loop.

Comment: Nothing after the `return` statement gets executed. What's the point of `array($randomString);` after `return $randomString;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$randomString = $strings[rand($minString, $maxString)];
```

should be:

```
$randomString .= $strings[rand($minString, $maxString)];
```

The `.` means to concatenate the value on the right to `$randomString`. Your code just replaces the value of the variable each time through the loop.

Comment: I will add, if the user did not understand, that @Barmar said: `.` is equal to do `$randomString = $randomstring . $strings[rand($minString, $maxString)];`

Comment: @P0lT10n That should  `$randomString . $string[...]`. PHP doesn't use `+` for concatenation.